# How to include all images in the Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

In an iOS project, if I wanna use an image, I should add a file reference to project navigator, it's not so convenient when there are many images to be included, is there any way to include all images automatically ?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean because it doesn't sound correct. Also, are you using an asset catalog or not? What code are you using to load a specific image?

Comment: There are many action texture atlas generated by tools, I wanna use these atlas directly by putting them in the project folder

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 7+ there is really one answer - you really should
use assets catalogs. You might find this  [tutorial](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-managing-images-xcode-5-asset-catalogs%20tutorial) and of course [the primary source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html).

Is a way to include all your images automatically? Well if you have all you images in one directory, you can drag&drop it to “assets catalog” view and that should be it - they all will be organised nicely so you will see what is missing, given that you named your assets properly (“~ipad”, “@2x”, “@3x” suffixes etc.). Although assets catalogs allow you much more.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This method needs dragging images to catalog, is there any way to include  all images directly without doing anything in the project?